# Is it possible to let a Kubeflow inference pipeline (KFServing) publish messages to Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, knative-eventing

I'm beginning to use Kubeflow and I've read about KFServing. There is this integration with Kafka to consume from a topic. What I need is to run an inference pipeline that consumes data from Kafka, does some data preproccessing, run the ML prediction and then **publish the result back to Kafka**, like this:

[image]

I know I could use Knative eventing to ingest data fro Kafka topic 1. Is there a way to use Kafka as a sink, or do I need to write a seperate container that publishes events to Kafka topic 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a new [`KafkaSink`](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/sink/kafka-sink/) resource in Knative Eventing that you can use to publish CloudEvents to a Kafka topic by sending them to the HTTP address exposed in the status.

Answer (score 0):

@openroy In this [video at 50:33](https://youtu.be/VHfyvoV5qns?t=3031), the speaker says that a Service (like KFServing) can return the HTTP response into a reply channel.